# Modify query params in Groovy on SAP BTP

Tags: groovy, sap-business-technology-platform

In SAP BTP I receive URL with 2 parameters and I need to transform them
in another 2 parameters for a second URL.

The rule, which I need to write in Groovy Script, are the following:

Query param `AA` becomes `CC`

and

`DD` becomes `BB` and the value gets incremented by 1

E.g.

`AA=1000&BB=0` -> `CC=1000&DD=1`

`AA=1000&BB=3000` -> `CC=1000&DD=3001`

I tried some Groovy Scripts, but it did not work.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.